# Determine directory in which current page is contained

Tags: php

How do you determine which directory contains the current Web page? For example, if someone visits `http://example.com/directory/page.php`, and the Web document root is `/var/www/html`, what code could I use to return this `/var/www/html/` directory?

Comment: There is [getcwd()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php), do you mean that?

Comment: That's perfect!

Comment: Contrary to what is posted here, `getcwd` returns the **current working directory**, not the full qualified path to the directory the file is in. Use the magic constant `__DIR__` for this. While the current working directory is usually the directory where the initial file is in, you should not depend on this behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use simply the function bellow:

```
getcwd()
```